# Defining maven submodules in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven multi-module project as follows:

```
app
 |- pom.xml
 |- child1
      |-pom.xml
      |-other files
 |-child2
      |- pom.xml
      |- aggregator.xml
```

The files are as follows:

**pom.xml in app**

```
<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2/aggregator.xml</module>
</modules>
```

**aggregator.xml in child2**

```
  <modules>
    <module>./pom.xml</module>
  </modules>
```

**pom.xml in child2**

```
contains the list of dependencies
```

When I run the command `mvn clean` inside the `app` directory, it gives the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol child2/aggregator.xml
```

How do I resolve the above error?

Also, if I wish to do the same in Intellij, how can I do that?

Comment: can you tell what you are trying to achieve with such configuration?  Declaring an "aggregator.xml" as a module is something I have never seen and I have no clue what you are trying to do

Comment: Actually, there are several `pom.xml`s inside the `child2` directory. They can be combined into one, but they have been separated. eg. there is a `./client-pom.xml` directory and there is also a `pom.xml` file. So, bascially just to keep the dependencies separate and the project clean.

Comment: I still have no clue on what you are trying to achieve. What's the meaning of "combining" several POMs into one?  How you are "combining" them?  Why not just make child2 another level of multi-module project and declare you "several POMs" as child projects of `child2`?

Comment: hmm, that maybe done. But, at the moment I have received this project as  I mentioned. Also, they have given me a special [console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) batch file. If I run the `mvn clean` command there, it builds succesfully. I am not sure what things have been configured in the batch file.

Comment: Unless you are clear on what you are trying to do and be specific on your problem (sorry it is definitely not now), I don't think people can help.  Especially what you are dealing with is not something conventional Maven setup, you have to be even more explicit.

Comment: As others already said. Your setup is strange. The parent (app) should only have a modules `child1, child2` nothing else. Maven is about Convention over Configuration...and as long as you don't explain why this is setup is so strange it's hard to say something about it...

Comment: You are doing this completely wrong. Stop it at once! Follow convention, or use gradle and be damned. Dependency management is done in the depenencyManagement tag in the parental root, not in a separate pom. There should be only one pom per module, not many. Reuse comes through aggregation and inheritance, not through splitting up the pom as if it were some second-rate scripting solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you wrote `Actually, there are several pom.xmls inside the child2 directory`. This way isn't possible. Every module has **one** `pom.xml`.

I'll give you an example for a multi module project, in which there is one child module which has children.

```
appRoot
  |  pom.xml
  |
  + child1
  |    pom.xml
  |
  + child2
      | pom.xml
      |
      + child2a
      |   pom.xml
      |
      + child2b
      |   pom.xml
```

**appRoot pom.xml:**

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>appRoot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>child1</module>
        <module>child2</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
      <!-- declare dependencies which are common to all modules -->
      <!-- including versionId -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

**child1 pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>appRoot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
      <!-- declare dependencies from parent dependency management -->
      <!-- without versionId (it's in the parent) -->

      <!-- declare dependencies which are module specific -->
      <!-- including versionId -->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**child2 pom.xml:**

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>appRoot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>child2a</module>
        <module>child2b</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

If it's necessary, you can add a `<dependencies>` and/or `<dependencyManagement>` section in child2.

**child2a and child2b pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child2a</artifactId>
    <!-- <artifactId>child2b</artifactId> -->
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
      <!-- declare dependencies from parent dependency management -->
      <!-- without versionId (it's in the parent) -->

      <!-- declare dependencies which are module specific -->
      <!-- including versionId -->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly right. Although submodules are correctly represented through aggregation (the `modules` tag), the inheritance part (`parent` tag), though very common, isn't necessary to make submodules work.

Comment: @EngineerDollery - using `<parent>` in a submodule isn't necessary by "syntax", but I would say it's best practice. The words _"isn't exactly right"_ sound like _"it's a bit wrong"_.

Comment: it sounds like I was communicating effectively then. Inheritance isn't 'best practice' either. It's just a tool that's useful in some situations and not useful in others (arguably, it's useful in most submodule situations, but that doesn't make it a 'best practice' either). What's important is understand when and where to use it, and when not to. Implying that it has something to do with the submodule mechanism would give the wrong impression. My comment was intended to flag this information for anyone who comes along to read this.

Comment: @EngineerDollery - I agree with that: _" Implying that it has something to do with the submodule mechanism would give the wrong impression."_